# python, shapely: How to determine if two polygons cross each other, while allowing their edges to overlap

Tags: python, shapely

I'm trying to find out whether two polygons cross each other. By 'cross' I mean their exteriors are allowed to touch each other, but their interior cannot:

Only the two **rightmost** solutions below are allowed:

[image]

I've tried using shapely intersects or crosses (and some others) but couldn’t find a built-in function that works (they usually relate to both interior and exterior).

Comment: Please post your edit as an answer and accept it! Don't use edits to show your solution.

Comment: Is there any reason 'not shape1.overlaps(shape2)' won't work?

Answer (score 4):

Did you look at the `touches` method?  It seems to do what you want.

If not, you could "roll your own".  For example, some variation of this:

```
def myTouches(poly1, poly2):
    return poly1.intersects(poly2) and not poly1.crosses(poly2) and not poly1.contains(poly2)
```

Or, assuming your shapes are just polygons, you could look at the collection returned by `intersection`.  If it contains only `LineStrings` or a single `Point` then they just "touch".  If it contains anything else (multiple `Points` and/or other polygons) then they overlap.

**Edit:**
Now that I see your picture, you'll probably also need to use the `disjoint` method in addition to `touches`.

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution that worked for the OP (taken from question):

```
if ((pol1.intersects(pol2) == False) and (pol1.disjoint(pol2) == True)) or ((pol1.intersects(pol2) == True) and (pol1.touches(pol2) == True)):
    allowed = True
elif (pol1.intersects(polMe) == True) and (pol1.disjoint(polMe) == False) and (pol1.touches(polMe) == False):
    allowed = False
```